# Firebase Google Authentication Error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

While making the Google Authentication feature with Firebase, I got an error like this. The problem is sometimes it logs in but sometimes it doesn't work.
I guess it's an async error or something...

Is there anything I did wrong?

(I'm very new to using Firebase, and I was writing code following some Firebase lectures. which was quite old, so I also needed to check recent documentation from time to time.)

```
const onSocialClick = async (e) => {
        const {
            target: { name },
        } = e;
        let provider;
        if (name === 'google') {
            // Creates the provider object.
            provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            provider.addScope('profile');
            provider.addScope('email');
        } else if (name === 'github') {
            provider = new GithubAuthProvider();
            provider.addScope('repo');
        }
        const user = await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    };
```

[image: This is the error I got on my browser]

Comment: My guess is that the `provider` variable isn't guaranteed to be set (because you have an `if` and an `else if` -- but what if neither condition is true?).

Can you add an `else` condition, and throw in a console.log to see if that edge case is being hit? And if so, maybe you can use that to help understand that edge case, and then handle it.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Thank you!! As you said, I added else condition and it came out it was being hit.